# How to select two same column from single table in single select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called Employee having columns empId, empName, managerId. here manager is an employee. how do i get employee-name and manager-name from the above table.

Comment: self join and inner query can solve your problem

Comment: MySQL is not Postgres. Pick one

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc425/6

Answer (score 2):

Join the table with itself (note the use of aliases to disambiguate the two):

```
SELECT e.empName AS employeeName, 
    m.empName AS managerName
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Employee m ON e.managerId = m.empId
```

Comment: +1 for ***note the use of aliases to disambiguate the two ***

Answer (score 1):

Try joining the table to itself with an alias:

```
SELECT
    Employee.empName AS employeeName,
    Manager.empName AS managerName
FROM Employee
JOIN Employee AS Manager
ON Employee.managerId = Manager.empId
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table employee
 (
   empid int , 
   empName nvarchar(500),
   mgrid int 

 )

insert into employee select 1,'ra',0 
insert into employee select 2,'ma',1
```

sub query to get manager name

```
select *
 ,(select empName  from employee as e where oe.mgrid=e.empid) as managername
from employee as oe
```

or

```
SELECT
    employee.empName AS employeeName,
    Manager.empName AS managerName
FROM employee
JOIN employee AS Manager
ON employee.mgrid = Manager.empId
```

[sql fiddle for this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc425/6)